# homomorphism and linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been told that a homomorphism between 2 groups (G,*) and (H,.) is a map L:G -> H such that L(g1 * g2) = L(g1).L(g2) for every g1,g2 elements of G ie such that in some sense the structure is preserved.
my question is what is meant by 'structure is preserved' and also I cant make much sense out of this definition a simpler explanation would be of much help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\;L(g_1*g_2)=L(g_1)\cdot L(g_2)\;$ means the operation in $\;G\;$ is $\;*\;$ , and the one in $\;H\;$ is $\;\cdot\;$

This is the beginning of understanding "preservation of structure". For example, if $\;G\;$ is abelian this means that

$$L(g_1)\cdot L(g_2)=L(g_1*g_2)=L(g_2*g_1)=L(g_2)\cdot L(g_1)$$

so that $\;L(G)\;$ is an abelian  subgroup of $\;H\;$ .

Similar things can be said about (in)finiteness of elements orders and many other properties that are preserved under homomorphisms. you just will have to wait until you get there.

Comment: alright i can understand it now . however am still struggling to understand what exactly is homomorphism

Comment: @samantha For example, if $\;G:=(0,\infty)\;$, under usual multiplication of real (positive) numbers, and $\;H=\Bbb R\;$ = the whole real numbers under usual addition, then the map $$L:G\to H\;,\;\;\;L(a):=\log a$$ is a group homomorphism, because $$L(ab):=\log(ab)=\log a+\log b=L(a)+L(b)$$ In fact, in this case we even have an **isomorphism**, meaning: a bijective homomorphism of groups.

Comment: clear explanation! thank you